# why the boundary test requires 3 values?

Tags: testing, boundary

In boundary testing, suppose the correct boundary is salary < 20000,then the guideline suggests for setting the test cases at boundary for 19999, 20000, 200001 to locate the defect. if it wrongly implemented as <= 20000, then the failure can be identifying by the 20000 test case.

The problem is the defect can be found by using 19999 and 20000 test case already (2 values), why the guideline suggest for using 3 values in boundary? what is the usage of the third values? is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, input values at extreme ends of input criteria cause more errors in system. Hence, we test the lower and upper boundaries as part of stress/negative testing. It is a general practise in software testing to have minimum of 3 tests to check boundary values. However, it is not mandatory. In your case, if the test fails in second test, you would not execute the third test as there is no need for it. Once the bug is fixed, then you will test all three values to ensure everything is as per the requirement. Software testing relies on tester's judgement and you should follow the usual guidelines but nothing is mandatory.